# Using Conditions on Terraform to deploy resources on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm currently developing new terraform modules and facing some problems validating existing resources such as resource groups.

Using the ARM template makes it possible to use the option deploy if it does not exist. But I couldn't find a similar solution on Terraform code.

For example, before creating a brand-new resource group. I would like to check if the subscription contains it and if not, create it.

```
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "mssql_server_resource_group" {
  name     = var.mssql_resource_group_name
  location = "eastus"

  # Check if resource group exists before creating
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes        = [tags] # Ignore tag changes to prevent unnecessary updates
    create_before_destroy = true   # Create a new resource before destroying the existing one
  }
}
```

I found the above example, but it does not work.

Comment: That's generally an anti-pattern of terraform and IAC. Either your state file should manage the resource or it shouldn't. While there are ways to do it using things like data lookups and try and count methods but really just cause you can do something doesn't mean you should

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the resource group already exists, You can try the below code which worked for me.

I tried with the `count` operator to check the condition as follows:

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
variable "resource_group"{
type = string
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = var.resource_group
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  count = length(data.azurerm_resource_group.example) == 0 ? 1 : 0
  name     = var.resource_group
  location = "eastus"
}
```

`terraform init`:

[image]

After I run the Terraform plan, it prompts me for the `resource group` variable. I used the existing one, and the output is as follows.

[image]

To verify again, I ran `terraform plan` with the new resource group name, and it returned the status `"resource not found"`. You can then check the status and proceed accordingly.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the below command to view the `Terraform state` file, including the `resource ID`. If the resource exists, it retrieves the following resource information.

```bash
terraform state show azurerm_resource_group.example
```

[image]